# How to implement a multicolumn list view with vertical divider for each item in the row. Which make the item in the list should look like grids

Tags: android, listview, listbox

friends I want to design a customized list view. The each row in the list view will contain four columns.I have designed a separate row.xml like this.

`

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/index"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/Invested"
     android:layout_width="70dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/Revenue"
     android:layout_width="60dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

`

Now, the list View will be having the divider for each row. **All I need is the vertical divider between each item in the list.** please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put an empty, narrow (2dp or so) TextView with a different background color between each element in your row layout.

The divider TextView would look something like this:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/verticalline"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/divider"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip" />
```

Comment: It does not need to be a TextView. I think View should be enough. It will be faster with View.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty view for this purpose. Something like this will work:

```
 <view
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
```

You can use this as a divider in between two columns.
But I can't understand why you are not using a GridView if you want to display a grid(2D) of data.
With your approach you can achieve the same result but this will increase your work and code complexity.
GridView will be a better option.